# Adding User enabled/disabled information to userinfo in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, identity-management

In one of my projects, I need to know what is the current status of the user (i.e. enabled/disabled) from userinfo in keycloak.

If any of you know how to get it via POST request, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By current status, if you are referring to whether the user is `enabled` or not.
The [Official KeyCloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) will help you.

Look out for `Get Representation Of The User` in the documentation.

This postman Collection [here](https://www.postman.com/zartu/workspace/e-t-s-public-workspace/example/7294517-917b4002-af82-4c91-bbab-39c5b830ace1) would be helpful.

Tip -> `realm` is the **realm name** and *not the realm id*.
[image: Postman Collection Image for Get User Information.]